# Add selected values from multi column into one column separated by ','

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select values from multiple columns into one column.  I have 2 separate columns from which i want to get name,address,state,zip in following format in SQL Server 2008

Name (new line)

```
address,state,zip
```

Name (new line)

```
address,state,zip
```

Query:

```
select 
    name + char(13) + concat(address,',', state,',', zip)   
from 
    tbl1  
join 
    tbl2 on....
```

I am not able to get the desired output. I get `concat` is not a recognized built in function name.

Comment: Have you tried using [Coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)?

Comment: Don't format data in SQL... That's what your APP/UI is for.  and concat is new to SQL 2012 not in 2008.  in 2008 just use + operator  See-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550307/how-do-i-use-the-concat-function-in-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: name + char(13) + address + ',' +  state + ',' +  zip does not work? You may of course need to wrap the columns with ISNULL(col,'')

Comment: so, it is not a better idea to format even if I am writing stored procedures and display in grid?

Comment: `CONCAT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** - it's just not available in the 2008 version yet

Answer (score 0):

You could use `+` operator and cast the `zip` field as varchar directly like this:

For example:

```
select 'Dara Singh' + char(13) + '1234 Main Street' + ',' + 'NY' + ',' 
        + cast(95825 as varchar(10))
```

This is how your query would look:

```
select name + char(13) + [address] + ',' + [state] + ',' + cast([zip] as varchar(10))
from tbl1 join tbl2 on....
```

Comment: thanks nepali rookie. I had to use rtrim() to format but new line character char(13) doesn't seem to work

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no way to do a carriage return line break unless you want to print those values. In that case, you just do `Print 'Dara Singh' + char(13) + '1234 Main Street' + ',' + 'NY' + ',' + cast(95825 as varchar)`

Comment: use char(13)+char(10) See-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string

Comment: @xQbert This is only possible if you are doing a PRINT. And, I believe he is looking for line break in the resultset.