# Sqlzoo SELECT within SELECT Tutorial #5

Tags: sql, select

**My Question is:**

> Germany (population 80 million) has the largest population of the
>   countries in Europe. Austria (population 8.5 million) has 11% of the
>   population of Germany.
>
> Show the name and the population of each country in Europe. Show the
>   population as a percentage of the population of Germany.

**My answer:**

```
SELECT name,CONCAT(ROUND(population/80000000,-2),'%')
FROM world
WHERE population = (SELECT population
                    FROM world
                      WHERE continent='Europe')
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question was incomplete and was taken from [here](http://www.sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial)

This is the answer

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  CONCAT(ROUND((population*100)/(SELECT population 
                                 FROM world WHERE name='Germany'), 0), '%')
FROM world
WHERE population IN (SELECT population
                     FROM world
                     WHERE continent='Europe')
```

I was wondering about sub-query as from OP'S question it wasn't clear (at least to me). The reason is that  "world" table (as the name suggest, I have to admit) contains all world country whereas we're interested only into european one. Moreover, the population of Germany has to be retrieved from DB because it's not extacly 80.000.000; if you use that number you receive back 101% as Germany population.

Comment: The last part of the SQL, WHERE population ... is redundant. You can just use WHERE continent = "Europe" instead of that blob.

Comment: I'm getting the following output for this
SQLZOO system error:
error

Answer (score 3):

When using sql server in SQL Zoo, then don't use `CONCAT`:

I think SQL Zoo uses a version of SQL Server that doesn't support `CONCAT` and furthermore it looks like you have to do a `CAST`. Instead concatenate with the use of '+'. Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550307/how-do-i-use-the-concat-function-in-sql-server-2008-r2).

I figure the script should be something like beneath (though I haven't got it to my desired stated, because of the fact I want to result to look like 3%;0%;4%;etc. instead of 3.000000000000000%;0.000000000000000%;4.000000000000000%;etc.. And I start a new topic for that one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072858/show-no-decimals-result-in-sql-server)).

`SELECT 
  name, 
  CAST(ROUND(population*100/(SELECT population FROM world WHERE name='Germany'), 0) as varchar(20)) +'%'
FROM world
WHERE population IN (SELECT population
                     FROM world
                     WHERE continent='Europe')`

Answer (score 1):

```
    select name, CONCAT(ROUND((population/(select population from world where name = "Germany"))*100),"%") 
    from world
    where continent= "Europe"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, CONCAT(ROUND(population/(SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany')*100,0), '%')
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing (Aug 16th, 2022), the accepted answer is a percentage without trailing 0s.

Using CONCAT and CAST solves this.

```
SELECT name, CONCAT(CAST(100*ROUND((population / (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name ='Germany')), 2) AS INT), '%')
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe';
```

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL? For MySQL, `INT` cause an error. I changed `INT` to `DECIMAL`, still no luck passing.

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL

Answer (score 0):

sub query should be return multiple data so you can use in function like this

```
  SELECT name,CONCAT(ROUND(population/80000000,-2),'%')
    FROM world
    WHERE population IN (SELECT population
                        FROM world
                          WHERE continent='Europe')
```

Comment: If you want percentage then you will be change division 80000000 to 800

Comment: You can edit question and add example of data and accepted result

Answer (score 0):

Below added code snippet

```
select name, concat (round(population/(select population from world where 
name='germany')*100,0), '%') from world where continent='Europe'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```sql
SELECT name, concat(format(ROUND(population / (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany') * 100, 5), '0'), '%') AS percentage
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe';
```