# Show no decimals result in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In a certain script that works with SQL Server 2008 (though I'm not sure of the version) I get results like 3.000000000000000%;0.000000000000000%;4.000000000000000%;etc. and instead I would like them to be like 3%;0%;4%;etc.

I already tried to CAST as integer, but that doesn't work. I think because I want the '%' in the result.

Has anyone an idea or can someone tell me it just isn't possible in SQL Server?

The script is as below

```
SELECT name, CAST(ROUND(population*100/(SELECT population 
                                        FROM world 
                                        WHERE name='Germany'), 0) as varchar(20)) +'%' 
FROM world 
WHERE population IN (SELECT population 
                     FROM world WHERE continent='Europe');
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This looks like homework, and formatting is generally handled in the presentation layer, not the DB layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this. you have to use as INT

```
SELECT name, CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(ROUND(population*100/(SELECT population 
                                        FROM world 
                                        WHERE name='Germany'), 0) as INT))+'%'
FROM world 
WHERE population IN (SELECT population 
                     FROM world WHERE continent='Europe');
```

Comment: `int + '%'` will give `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.`

Comment: @paresh-gami: CONCAT doesn't work in SQL Server 2008 I think. Also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550307/how-do-i-use-the-concat-function-in-sql-server-2008-r2. Do you maybe have an other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid answer using `CONCAT` for the `%` symbol, `CAST` and `ROUND`.

```
SELECT name, CONCAT(
               CAST(
              ROUND(100 * population / (SELECT population 
                                        FROM world
                                        WHERE name = 'Germany'), 0) AS INT), '%')
              AS percentage
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe';
```