# How to replace values which are equal in a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below column in a table which has same string values. I need to replace the strings which are equal for eg:

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | Column_Name |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Imports     |
|  2 | Imports     |
|  3 | Exports     |
|  4 | Exports     |
+----+-------------+
```

**Which needs to be replaced as :**

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | Column_Name |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Imports1    |
|  2 | Imports2    |
|  3 | Exports1    |
|  4 | Exports2    |
+----+-------------+
```

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL query ?

> The purpose of doing this is that I'm using the ***'Column_Name'*** string
>   values in the dynamic SQL to replace the Integer values because of the
>   same names the different values for the column are not getting
>   replaced.

Comment: Can you show an extended sample data set?  Is there any order at all to the `ID` numbering scheme and the column name?

Comment: No I created a temporary table with ID as(Integer identity)... the column names have the ID values as per the insertion. All I need is the replacement for similar string names with some altenate name or number added to it....  thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET Name = Name + CAST(RN AS varchar(1)) FROM -- varchar(10)
                    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) AS RN
                     FROM Your_Table) AS A
```

Comment: You're welcome. P/s: `CAST(RN AS varchar(1))` just support 1-->9, if you want more, you can extend `varchar(n) -- n=2 (1-->99), n=3 (1-->999),...`

Comment: Hi... when i use the querey all the string names are getting appended with numeric value1..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single which achieves what you want.  It performs a union of two inner queries, each of which numbers the `Import` and `Export` records from 1, in the order of their original `ID` values.  The outer query selects the `ID` along with the new `Column Name`.

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT([Column Name], NewID)
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, [Column Name],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS NewID
    FROM your_table
    WHERE [Column Name] = 'Exports'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, [Column Name],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS NewID
    FROM your_table
    WHERE [Column Name] = 'Imports'
)
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: It works, but just select, i think he would update his table :)

Comment: Thanks @NguyễnHảiTriều your answer is way more concise.  I will leave this up in case someone just wants to select.

Comment: i fear
[CONCAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550307/how-do-i-use-the-concat-function-in-sql-server-2008-r2) will be available from 2012.

Comment: @Ragul The link you provided seems to say that `CONCAT` is available in SQL Server 2008 and beyond.  This is a relatively old feature.